# Is it possible to view all the attribute data in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, attribute-table, fields-attributes

I use QGIS to map and store local history data. Because of this my point attribute data contains a lot of text. Since the textbox are so small it's hard to use and present the information. Is it possible to view this data in a way simular to Google Earth?

Comment: what is _"a way similar to Google Earth"_ ?

Comment: Which "textbox" are you using? Identify window, HTML map tip, attribute table, label item in the print composer, ... ? There are ways to change the font size in all these.

Comment: In google earth you can see all the attribute data, like a text document without any table.

Comment: Sorry, no textbox. I want to see the full text i add to the fields in the attribute table, when im using the identify object funcion. When i use this function and click on a point, the attributedata will show in it's own window, but i can only se a portion of the data. Did this make more sence ?

Answer (score 6):

I think using HTML map tip is what you want, to activate it open the Layer Properties dialog for a layer and select the Display tab, there you could configure the map tip (use HTML and CSS) to show the information you want when you hoover above a point in your map.

see [this blog post from Nathan Woodrow](https://nathanw.net/2012/08/05/html-map-tips-in-qgis/) for an exemple.

Comment: Thank you! I think that will do. It's more or less what im looking for.